# \mathbf ignored in table column specification

Tags: tables, math-mode, bold, columns

I have a long table whose columns are to be typeset in math-mode and bold. To avoid repeating `\(\mathbf{cell value}\)` for each row, I defined in a column specification how each cell under it was to be formatted. The `array` package came in handy on this one.

Putting everything into use I wound up with this MWE.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}

  \begin{tabular}{>{\(\mathbf\bgroup}l<{\egroup\)}}
    a
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Yet, the `a` character isn't rendered in math boldface. LaTeX instead picked the math default font. I.e. italicized for letters. Very strangely, whenever I swap in `\mathrm` for `\mathbf` I get the right font: upright roman.

Is this normal? Is LaTeX using math default font because it failed to resolve something?

Finally was I to tediously enclose each and every cell value within `\mathbf{}` it would work.

There's something amiss around.

Can anybody come up with an answer? Or clear things up?

Answer (score 3):

If you use

```
\mathbf\bgroup
```

Then the argument of `\mathbf` is `\bgroup` you can not use `\bgroup` `\egroup` to delimit macro arguments in TeX.

What happens if you pass `\bgroup` as the argument depends mostly on luck. With `\mathrm` you get lucky, with `\mathbf` less so if it is the first occurrence as `\mathbf` sets up the fonts the first time it is used.  You could use a different interface or just change you luck by making sure that `\mathbf` is used earlier, eg in a box that you discard.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array}

\begin{document}
\sbox0{$\mathbf{a}$}
  \begin{tabular}{>{\(\mathbf\bgroup}l<{\egroup\)}}
    a
  \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer.  What you suggest is some sort of hack to deal with this condition.  However I was thinking of the `\bgroup`, `\egroup` macro pair as delimiters to arguments. As you pointed out this isn't the case.  AFAIK these macros are resp. defined to `{` and `}`. So, in my case I don't really catch on to the reason they're mistaken for arguments. If it were the case, wouldn't compilation raise an error like `missing {` or something similar?

Comment: @DavidC (by the way are you the same David C registered [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/14194/davidc) if so you could ask the moderators to merge the accounts) (I know you are not me:-)

Comment: @DavidC any tex macro you can omit the `{}` if the argument is a single token, `\frac 1 2` or `\frac12` are  the same as `\frac{1}{2}` (just bad style) and similarly `\mathbf\bgroup` is the same as `\mathbf{\bgroup}`

Comment: No, we're different people. Now, I see more clearly, thx.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `collcell`

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage{array} % collcell uses array
\usepackage{collcell}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{>{\(\collectcell\mathbf}l<{\endcollectcell\)}}
a
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The main reason is that `\bgroup` can't be used for delimiting an argument; in some cases it *seems* to work, but it's by chance, usually.

After `\collectcell` one has to put a macro taking an argument, and `\mathbf` is good.